# Как вывести новость детально на отдельной странице в битрикс 1с?

Tags: битрикс

А как в битрикс вывести "новость детально" на отдельной странице. Я просто делаю на компоненте news.list и дельная новость выходит на той же странице. Как сделать, чтобы она выходила на отдельной странице? Буду признателен любой помощи!

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Приведите примеры того, что получается сейчас, и того, что вы хотите получить. Пока что вопрос можно понять по-разному, и соответственно, будут разные ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В нужном шаблоне компонента (например .default или bootstrap_v4) в файле template.php, в коды такого вида

```
<a href="<?= $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"] ?>">
```

добавьте target="_blank"

```
<a href="<?= $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"] ?>" target="_blank">
```